# how to write delete query in advance query in outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I am tried to write delete query using advanced query. But don't no how to write query in advance query still I tried but I am getting error.Please help me how to write query with example.

I just want to delete all the data from "EnvelopeHeader" entity.

[image: I got following error]

Comment: Those curly brackets don't look even slightly right for any SQL I've ever seen. Square brackets are the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE table.column IN (...)
```

That means your inner query must return a list of values with the same type as table.column.

In your case your inner query:

1. Is selecting a bunch o columns, and should only be selecting one
2. When selecting multiple columns you need commas to separate the columns you want to select col1, col2
3. You need to specify the FROM statement for the inner query

It should be something like

```
DELETE FROM {table}
WHERE {table}.[column] in
(SELECT {table}.[column] FROM {table} WHERE <condition>)
```

Also don't forget that if you want to use parameters, you can refer to them by using @param_name

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this version of SQL. However, my hunch tells me you need to wrap that entire select statement in two round brackets. And probably the select statement should only include one column.

Something like this

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE ID IN
( select EH_id FROM some_other_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all records in that entity simply use

`DELETE * FROM {EnvelopeHeader}`